# Date range validation inside a wrapper directive. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

How to validate both `requestDateFrom` and `requestDateTo` using a wrapper directive (let's call it **drange**) so that the range is valid only when distance between the dates equals 1?

```
<div ranger distance="1">
    <div>
        <div>
            <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <input required ng-model="formCtrl.dateFrom" name="requestDateFrom" type="text"/>
            </datepicker>                       
        </div>
        <div ng-messages="_form.requestDateFrom.$error" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="required">Enter start date</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- range end date.. the same markup -->
</div>
```

**Update: Came up with a solution**

Here's what I came up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/hfwpe1bw/38/

As you can see I define three directives:

- **ranger** (checks dates distance)

  ```
  function rangerDirective() {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          scope: {distance: '@'},
          controller: function($scope) {
              var rangeStartConfig = null;
              var rangeEndConfig = null;

              this.rangeStartChanged = function(config) {
                  rangeStartConfig = config;
                  validateRange();
              };

              this.rangeEndChanged = function(config) {
                  rangeEndConfig = config;
                  validateRange();
              };

              function validateRange() {
                  // check, set validity 
                  rangeStartConfig.modelCtrl.$setValidity('range', isRangeValid);
                  rangeEndConfig.modelCtrl.$setValidity('range', isRangeValid);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **range-start** (calls **`rangeStartChanged()`** on **ranger**'s controller)

  ```
  ↓ see the example below
  ```
- **range-end** (calls **`rangeEndChanged()`** on **ranger**'s controller)

  ```
  function rangeEndDirective() {
      return {
          require: ['^ranger', '^ngModel'],
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
              scope.$watch(attrs.rangeEndValue, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  controllers[0].rangeEndChanged({
                      newValue: newValue,
                      modelCtrl: controllers[1]
                  });
              });
          }
      };
  }
  ```

I don't know how to do this better (leaving this question open), it fits my needs but I'm not sure if it's not hackish.

Comment: @Mistalis of course. So far I have tried to use validating directives on both dates that follow the pattern described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28063268/532675). Yet It's not enough for me to understand how to access (and operate with) children models. Plus I'm constantly searching, you believe that. Yet haven't found the right example.

Comment: @lexeme  To solve the problem, some real code is needed. But your code context is not clear. Maybe a live demo is better.

Comment: @Mistalis I updated the question. Is there anything I can do better?